# rearrange my data frame rows by a set order of index numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I rearrange my data frame rows by a set order of index numbers?

for example:

```
$    PatNum Response
1       3       r
2       4       r
3      10       r
4      13       nr
```

This goes on for a total of 40 rows. I want to make row one starting with row 13, then 26, 1, 2, 61, 62, 63, etc. So it would look like:

```
$   PatNum Response
13      1       nr
26      2       nr
1       3       r
2       4       r
```

Comment: instead of copy/pasting your data, provide output of `dput(head(yourdataset))`.

Comment: Are you just trying to sort the` PatNum` column in descending order?

Comment: yes i want the "patNum" in ascending order from 1 to 40, but i want the number's corresponding "response" to move with the "PatNum"...does that make sense?

Comment: `library(dplyr); dat %>% arrange(PatNum)`?

Comment: This didn't work the way I wanted to but I can still use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Create example data

```
one <- c(3, 4, 10, 1, 2, 5)
two <- c("nr", "nr", "r", "r", "nr", "nr")
data <- cbind(one, two)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
names(data) <- c("PatNum", "Response")
data$PatNum <- as.numeric(as.character(data$PatNum))
```

## Sort example data

```
data <- data[order(data$PatNum) , ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be a long way around it though